# ssl handshake error with ip range (C-Block)

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, javax

I use a third party tool to inspect webpages. For some URL's with SSL, i can do my analysis.

But for a special IP C-Block, i get SSL handshake errors. Can someone explain me the error with solution? The pages are available via browser! I have try some ideas from the forum. No result.
What we have tried

- Call Website via Browser - ok
- Try to use the programm on notebook in the same network - ok
- Insert via Keytool the SSL-Cert - no change
- Deactivate Firewall - no result
- Uninstall XAMPP & reinstall JAVA - no result

Is it possible, the installation of XAMPP has changed something?

```
    2016-12-17 12:32:09 [pool-10-thread-4] ERROR com.agilemind.commmons.io.searchengine.analyzers.aC - 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.url.URLPageReader.getContent(URLPageReader.java:78) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.cache.b.retrieve(b.java:2) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.cache.b.retrieve(b.java:1) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.cache.impl.LockedCache.get(LockedCache.java:10) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.cache.CachedPageReader.getContent(CachedPageReader.java:9) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.AjaxPageReader.getContent(AjaxPageReader.java:4) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.PageReaderUtil.getResponseCodeFollowSingleRedirect(PageReaderUtil.java:9) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commmons.io.searchengine.analyzers.aC.a(aC.java:4) ~[searchengines.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commmons.io.searchengine.analyzers.j.a(j.java:10) ~[searchengines.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commmons.io.searchengine.analyzers.j.check(j.java:15) ~[searchengines.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commmons.io.searchengine.analyzers.f.check(f.java:3) ~[searchengines.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.application.modules.io.cache.a.retrieve(a.java:3) ~[commons-application.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.application.modules.io.cache.a.retrieve(a.java:1) ~[commons-application.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.cache.impl.LockedCache.get(LockedCache.java:10) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.application.modules.io.cache.FactorValueCache.get(FactorValueCache.java:18) ~[commons-application.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.sitescan.util.operations.UpdateDomainFactorOperation.execute(UpdateDomainFactorOperation.java:11) ~[websiteauditor.jar:?]
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.concurrent.util.operations.Operation.executeOperation(Operation.java:126) ~[commons.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentEncoding(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at com.agilemind.commons.io.pagereader.url.URLPageReader.getContent(URLPageReader.java:97) ~[commons.jar:?]
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: If you look around at this site you might notice that handshake errors can be cause by a variety of errors, like missing or wrong SNI extension, no shared ciphers, protocol mismatch, wrong server setup ... . The information you provide here are not enough to find out the real cause so please check out by reading the other posts about the topic which information are needed and provide these.

Comment: We have done some steps.

Comment: Call in the browser, try to call another https-pages via our software, insert specific SSL Cert via Keytool... 
No result

Comment: Is a collision with XAMPP possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we have tried to use jre8u101 instead jre8u111.
And than, the software runs. But the big question is: What happens with the new version and what is the reason? XAMPP has also no influence. I'M not a programmer, but gives the release notes a hint?